# Query with WHERE clause on timestamp does not return results on one table but fine on the other

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have 2 tables A and B with `reporting_date_time as timestamp(6)`.
When I query table A executes fine but not on table B

This is my query:

```
select * from A where reporting_date_time = ?
```

I use JDBC `PreparedStatements` and pass the argument through: `prepStmt.setTimestamp(1, myTimestampVar);`.

private java.sql.Timestamp myTimestampVar; 
myTimestampVar.toString shows the value as '2014-11-26 00:00:00.0'

Strange thing is that same application gets data from both tables in user testing, while it fails to do so in production even though it is the same JDBC driver on both environments.

I got oracle trace enabled and found that in table A timestamp is passed to the query as `26-NOV-14 12.00.00 AM`, while that in table B it is passed as `26-NOV-14 00.00.00`.

Why would it is sending it in two different formats?

Comment: `myTimestampVar` , looks like you are generating that timestamp. How you are generating it ?

Comment: DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
  Date date = null;
  long time = 0;
  if (!strDate.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
   date = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
   time = date.getTime();
   return new Timestamp(time);
  }
  
Where strDate is what i get from the form

Comment: You could try to pass an string and explicitly cast to date/timestamp on oracle-side to avoid format trouble, i.e. `where reporting_date_time = to_date( ? , 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )`and then pass your value as matching string.

Comment: In fact there are more tables and this works for all the other tables except one. It works fine in uat for all tables and only in production we have issue with one particular table.

Comment: I even changed prepStmt.setTimestamp(1, myTimestampVar) to prepStmt.setTimestamp(1, myTimestampVar, cal)                         where Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));                          Still doesn't work